# IEnumerable<T>.Contains with predicate

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, contains, predicate

I need just to clarify that given collection contains an element.

I can do that via `collection.Count(foo => foo.Bar == "Bar") > 0)` but it will do the unnecessary job - iterate the whole collection while I need to stop on the first occurrence.

But I want to try to use `Contains()` with a predicate, e.g. `foo => foo.Bar == "Bar"`.

Currently `IEnumerable<T>.Contains` has two signatures:

- `IEnumerable<T>.Contains(T)`
- `IEnumerable<T>.Contains(T, IEqualityComparer<T>)`

So I have to specify some variable to check:

```
var collection = new List<Foo>() { foo, bar };
collection.Contains(foo);
```

or write my custom `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` which will be used against my collection:

```
class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo f1, Foo f2)
    {
        return (f1.Bar == f2.Bar); // my predicate
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo f)
    {
        return f.GetHashCode();
    }   
}
```

So are there any other methods to use predicate?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
.Any(predicate)
```

sounds like what you want; returns `bool`, returning `true` as soon as a match is found, else `false`. There is also:

```
.All(predicate)
```

which behaves in a similar way, returning `false` as soon as a non-match is found, else `true`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Any(predicate)`.
It will return true or false depending if the predicate exists in a certain collection.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the `IEnumerable<T>.Any` extension.