# Using Contains on an List in a different way

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, contains

I have this code which i want to change:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo path in currDirs) {

            if (!newDirs.Contains(path)) { 

                MyLog.WriteToLog("Folder not Found: "+path.Name + "in New Folder. ",MyLog.Messages.Warning);
                currNoPairs.Add(path);
            }
        }
```

In the If part i don't want to check the path i want to check the path.Name.
So how can i use the Contains method on the properties.
the goal is to sort out all folders that have not the same name in the list of Current Directory List and New Directory List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See - [IEnumerable<T>.Contains with predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328760/ienumerablet-contains-with-predicate)

Those functions that take "predicates" (boolean functions that signify a match) will let you do more complex checks. In this case, you can use them to compare sub-properties instead of the top-level objects.

The new code will look something like this:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo path in currDirs) {
    if (!newDirs.Any(newDir => newDir.Name == path.Name)) {
        // TODO: print your error message here
        currNoPairs.Add(path.Name);
    }
}
```

---

In reply to your comment:

> Okay i understood, but whats the diffrence between any and contains then?

[`List<T>.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

This method goes through each item in the list, seeing if that item is equal to the value you passed in.

The code for this method looks a little like this (simplified here for illustration):

```
for(var item in yourList) {
    if(item.Equals(itemYouPassedIn) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

As you see, it can only compare top-level items. It doesn't check sub-properties, unless you are using a custom type that overrides the default `Equals` method. Since you're using the built in `DirectoryInfo` types, you can't override this `Equals` behavior without making a custom derived class. Since there's easier ways to do this, I wouldn't recommend this approach unless you need to do it in a ton of different places.

[`IEnumerable<T>.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

This method goes through each item in the list, and then passes that item to the "predicate" function you passed in.

The code for this method looks a little like this (simplified for illustration):

```
for(var item in yourList) {
    if(isAMatch(item)) { // Note that `isAMatch` is the function you pass in to `Any`
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Your predicate function can be as complicated as you want it to be, but in this case, you'd just use it to check if the sub-properties are equal.

```
// This bit of code defines a function with no name (a "lambda" function).
// We call it a "predicate" because it returns a bool, and is used to find matches
newDir => newDir.Name == path.Name

// Here's how it might look like if it were defined as a normal function -
// this won't quite work in reality cause `path` is passed in by a different means,
// but hopefully it makes the lambda syntax slightly more clear
bool IsAMatch(DirectoryInfo newDir) {
    return newDir.Name == path.Name;
}
```

Since you can customize this predicate every place that you use it, this could be a better tactic. I'd recommend this style until you are doing this exact check in a bunch of places in your code, in which case a custom class might be better.

Comment: Okay i understood, but whats the diffrence between any and contains then?

Comment: @Ams1 tried to edit to give a detailed answer to your question. Feel free to keep commenting if it is still confusing :)

Comment: You, Sir are my god ! :D Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you check for property [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo path in currDirs) {

            if (!newDirs.Any(dir => dir.FullName == path.FullName)) { 

                MyLog.WriteToLog("Folder not Found: "+path.Name + "in New Folder. ",MyLog.Messages.Warning);
                currNoPairs.Add(path);
            }
        }
```

And by the way, your code could be written in a better way like this

```
var currDirsConcrete = currDirs.ToArray();
var pathsNotFound = "Following paths were not found \r\n " + string.Join("\r\n", currDirsConcrete.Where(d => d.FullName != path.FullName).ToArray());

var pathsFound = currDirsConcrete.Where(d => d.FullName == path.FullName).ToArray();

 MyLog.WriteToLog(pathsNotFound, MyLog.Messages.Warning);
```

Note: You can skip the first line currDirsConcrete if your currDirs is already an array or a list. I did this to avoid redetermining the enumerable.

Comment: how can dir.Name be equal path if dir is the path ? :/ sry im new its possible that im getting it wrong with Linq & lambda

Comment: @Ams1 DirectoryInfo object contains property called Name and Full Name, actually I think you want to use Full Name. Let me update

Answer (score 0):

I would use linq with `except` and implement a `DirComparator`

```
List<DirectoryInfo> resultExcept = currDirs.Except(newDirs, new DirComparator()).ToList();
```

Here the `IEqualityComparer<DirectoryInfo>`:

```
public class DirComparator : IEqualityComparer<DirectoryInfo> {

    public bool Equals(DirectoryInfo x, DirectoryInfo y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return x.Name.equals(y.Name);
    }

     public int GetHashCode(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(dir, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        return dir.Name == null ? 0 : dir.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

you could also use `intersect` if you want it the other way around.