# LINQ extension for optimising Skip() Take()

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-entities

I have been applying the optimization from this blog:
[RimDev.io](https://rimdev.io/optimizing-linq-sql-skip-take/)

```
context.Cars
.Where(x => context.Cars
.OrderBy(y => y.Id)
.Select(y => y.Id)
.Skip(50000)
.Take(1000)
.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

I want to convert this into a general LINQ extension, however, I am not sure how to refer to x.Id in Contains. It does not seem like something that you could pass as an expression but it does not then specifically reference an instance of x.

Update here goes in progress code:

```
public static class LinqExtension {
    public static IQueryable<TSource> SkipTake<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> selector, int skip, int take)
    where TSource: class {
      return source.Where(x=> source.OrderBy<TSource,TKey(selector)
               .Select(selector)
               .Skip(skip)
               .Take(take)
               .Contains( ??? ));
     }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `context.Cars.OrderBy(y => y.Id).Skip(50000).Take(1000).ToList()` instead?  There's really no need to have that as a subquery.

Comment: The subquery forces an optimization to avoid bad performance when large values are used for Skip. The blog I linked explains this. You will get progressively worse performance querying the database with larger Skip values.

Comment: If you pass in a `Expression<Func<TEnity, TKey>> getKey` to use in the `OrderBy` and `Select`, have you tried `Contains(getKey(x))`

Comment: I updated the question about to provide code. selector(x) does not work for me, it does not seem like Linq expressions are callable in this way at least not in the version of C# I have.

Comment: The extension method you're proposing doesn't add anything useful, and in fact reduces code clarity by hiding the skip and take arguments behind a pair of int parameters.  Just use the original code from the blog instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this same pattern (with the sub-select optimization) is used everywhere in multiple projects because we extensively use pagination control and because performance of ordinary skip and take is terrible. Also even if what you are saying is true I would still like to understand how x could be referenced in the contains in a generic.

Comment: I don't doubt your need.  But what value does the extension method add to your project that the proper use of Skip and Take doesn't already provide?

Comment: It simplifies the application of the sub-select, I can point new people to the extension method rather than checking they are applying the pattern correctly after the fact. If you look carefully at what is being done this is different from merely apply OrderBy(x=>x.Id).Skip(10).Take(10)

Comment: If that doesn't work then I think you'd have to build the expression manually.

Comment: Try using `Any` or `All` with a predicate.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328760/ienumerablet-contains-with-predicate

Comment: Even exchanging Contains for Any or All. It is not obvious to me how I would build a predicate that references x in the where above. In this context x references a particular instance of TSource, rather than a general case of TSource. Unless the suggestion is to replace the where with Any or All?

Comment: Another option is if this is always used with a column named `Id` you can create an interface that exposes `Id` and apply it to the entities, then constrain the `TSource` to that interface and you can do `x => x.Id`.

Comment: OK.  If I have some time today I'll work out the code for you.  I'll have to stand up an EF6 instance and some data; haven't done that in awhile.

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that `x.Id` will refer to the same member as `selector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have stepped into the world of `Expression` tree building. Your question inspired me to create some new helpers to make this easier in certain cases.

Here are some extension methods that help with `Expression` tree manipulation and building:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static Expression Contains(this Expression src, Expression item) => src.Call("Contains", item);

    public static Expression Call(this Expression p1, string methodName, params Expression[] px) {
        var tKey = p1.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var containsMI = typeof(Queryable).MakeGenericMethod(methodName, px.Length + 1, tKey);
        return Expression.Call(null, containsMI, px.Prepend(p1));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces an Expression (reference Equals) with another Expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orig">The original Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="from">The from Expression.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The to Expression.</param>
    /// <returns>Expression with all occurrences of from replaced with to</returns>
    public static T Replace<T>(this T orig, Expression from, Expression to) where T : Expression => (T)new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);

    /// <summary>
    /// ExpressionVisitor to replace an Expression (that is Equals) with another Expression.
    /// </summary>
    public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        readonly Expression from;
        readonly Expression to;

        public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static class TypeExt {
    public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(this Type t, string methodName, int paramCount) =>
        t.GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.Name == methodName && mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition && mi.GetParameters().Length == paramCount).Single();

    public static MethodInfo MakeGenericMethod(this Type t, string methodName, int paramCount, params Type[] genericParameters) =>
        t.GetGenericMethod(methodName, paramCount).MakeGenericMethod(genericParameters);
}
```

Now you can create your `SkipTake` method - I am assuming the `Contains` member selector parameter is always the same member as the `selector` parameter.

```
public static class LinqExtension {
    public static IQueryable<TSource> SkipTake<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> selector, int skip, int take)
        where TSource : class {
        // x
        var xParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        var qBase = source.OrderBy(selector)
                          .Select(selector)
                          .Skip(skip)
                          .Take(take);
        // selector(x)
        var outerSelector = selector.Body.Replace(selector.Parameters[0], xParm);
        // source.OrderBy(selector).Select(selector).Skip(skip).Take(take).Contains(selector(x))
        var whereBody = qBase.Expression.Contains(outerSelector);
        // x => whereBody
        var whereLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource,bool>>(whereBody, xParm);
        return source.Where(whereLambda);
    }
}
```

To create the method, you need to build the lambda for the `Where` method manually. Rather than build the `qBase` `Expression` tree manually, I let the compiler do that for me, then use the resulting `Expression`. My `Call` helper makes it easy to create extension methods that correspond to the `Queryable` extension methods but work on `Expression` trees though, of course, you could just use `Call` directly for any `Queryable` methods you need (but then a `Constant` helper would be useful).

Once you've built the `whereLambda`, you just pass it to `Where` for the original `source`.

Comment: This is a superb solution! I also learned quite a lot looking at documentation related to Expression building and stepping thru the code. Based on my bench marking the execution times for this approach is also excellent. Thank you very much!